# Разное количество аргументов для программы (argc argv)

Tags: c++, argv

Задача состоит в том, чтобы программа, из консоли, могла работать с разным количеством аргументов, например: `name_program arg1 arg2(?) arg3(?)`

`arg2 arg3` могут отсутствовать, но в моем коде если я указал о существовании более одного аргумента то при его отсутствии при старте программа крашится.

Как тогда выполнять код при разном количестве входящих аргументов?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 1) {//if not inputted first argument
        std::cout << "enter \"I\" for write transactions" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "enter \"ls\" to display the list of accounts" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (std::string(argv[1]) == "I") {
        if (argc == 2) {//if not inputted second argument
            std::cout << "enter your transaction use (+) or (-)" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        } else if (argc == 3) {//if not inputted third argument
            std::cout << "enter name your account" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
        if (std::string(argv[2]) == "-h" || std::string(argv[2]) == "-help") {
            std::cout << "enter sum your transaction: " << std::endl;
            std::cout << "+10 for income" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "-10 for consumption" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
        WriteFile write(argv);
        write.inputText();
    } else if (std::string(argv[1]) == "ls") {
        if (argc == 2) {
            std::cout << "enter name your account" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
        if (argc == 3) {//здесь программа крашится когда я не ввожу третий аргумент
            ReadFiles readfiles(argv);
        }
        ReadFile read(argv);
        read.getDir();
        read.outText();
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите свой код. Никакой фундаментальной проблемы использования разного количества аргументов нет.

Comment: Использовать библиотечные функции обработки командной строки или самому всё прописывать руками. Если речь про аргументы после **--** (минус-минус), то тогда только самому считать и разбираться какие у них должны быть значения по умолчанию и как должна вести себя программа в их отсутствии.

Comment: Так у вас есть argc, анализируйте его и вы будете точно знать что операнда нет и не попытаетесь к нему обратится когда не надо

Comment: @0andriy `Использовать библиотечные функции обработки командной строки` - серьезно?) библиотеки, чтоб узнать сколько аргументов передали?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, абсолютно. Вы плохо читали мой комментарий (посмотрите на выделенный фрагмент **--**). Из пояснения автора не ясно, какое предназначение этих аргументов. Если два последних применяются как, например, опция (читаем или пишем) + имя файла, то очевидно, что `getopt()` здесь нужен, а не свой огород.

Comment: конструкторы были определены с учетом входящих данных, но программа всё равно считает, что я обязан ввести третий аргумент

Comment: Вам надо, чтобы было либо 0, либо более одного аргументов? Сделайте тогда условие `arvc.Length > 0 && arvc.Length == 1 => Error`.

Comment: 0 будет в случае простого запуска. Если из консоли запуск и всё равно 0, то волноваться вообще нет смысла - это одно и тоже...

Comment: @D .Stark мне нужно что бы при отсутствии аргумента при запуске, выполнялся код который я указал, но в моем случае это не работает. Программа все равно просит ввести третий аргумент.